# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined error while running react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, requirejs, node-modules, mern

My react application is not getting properly loaded and when I open browser console it is showing below error-

```
external node-commonjs "events":1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
        at Object.events (external node-commonjs "events":1:1)
        at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
        at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
        at ./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js (emitter.js:1:1)
        at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
        at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
        at ./node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js (dev-server.js:64:1)
        at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
```

So, can anyone please help me debug this error?